# if this measure isn't stored by the codec

Tags: java, lucene, codec

I have seem many methods in Lucene has following text:

> if this measure isn't stored by the codec.

For example size() method of org.apache.lucene.index.Terms class:

> public abstract long size() throws IOException
>
> Returns the number of terms for this field, or -1 if this measure
>   isn't stored by the codec. Note that, just like other term measures,
>   this measure does not take deleted documents into account.

What does it means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Codec is short for coder-decoder, and it's the implementation that handles how lucene indexes documents and what data is maintained there.

Classes like `Terms` (and it's underlying `TermsEnum`) are abstract and implemented by the codec itself.  Much of what is provided by them is useful, but supplemental, metadata.  Some codec implementations may not store much of the data.  In that case, the specification is to return -1 as a flag to generally indicate that the piece of data you are asking simply isn't available.

In other cases, like `Terms.getSumTotalTermFreq`, it can return -1 if you've configured it not to store the data your asking for.